# RSpec locating resource path

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have a little project (non Rails) and I'm using RSpec for testing.  In order to load models I'm using:

```
require_relative "../lib/checkout"
```

However I'm encountering the problem with loading config files, for instance, the test no longer locates my "items.csv" when the following:

```
CSV.foreach("items.csv") do |row|
```

Note that the problem occurs only when spec is run from the spec directory, i.e:

```
rspec checkout_spec.rb
```

Running it from the project root is fine:

```
rspec spec/checkout_spec.rb
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`CSV.foreach` uses the current directory to find the file. You should probably use `File.expand_path` to get to an absolute path to `items.csv` to avoid this problem.

Edited to add an example

Assuming that the file is at `root/items.csv`, and the ruby file with this code is at `root/lib/file.rb`, you could write

```
path = File.expand_path File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'items.csv')
CSV.foreach path do |row|
  # rest of code...
```

Comment: Could you give a quick example of using `File.expand_path` for that purpose?  Would appreciated it.

Comment: `File.expand_path( "items.csv", File.dirname(__FILE__))` - will get a full pathname of `items.csv` that's located at the same directory as current ruby file `File.expand_path( "../items.csv", File.dirname(__FILE__))` - same, but `items.csv` is one level up

Comment: Doh, didn't realize `#expand_path` took a second arg. Learned something new.